# Angular js template won`t show variables from pouch db

Tags: angularjs, scope, pouchdb

I`m trying to get data from pouchDB, I wrote factory for it.

```
fac.factory('dbFactory',function(){
var db = new PouchDB('dbname');

return {
    post: function(data){
        db.post({
        title: data
        }, function (err, response) {
            if(err){console.log(err)};
            console.log(response) 
            return response
        });
    },
    get: function(date){
        db.get(date, function(err, doc) {
            if(err){console.log(err)};
            console.log(doc);
            return doc

        });
    },
```

When I do this

```
$scope.drivers = dbFactory.get('2EC8999B-FC24-4AF6-A171-A43C8414C3D1');
```

I got data in JS console, but in template the variable {{drivers}} are empty.

```
Object_id: "2EC8999B-FC24-4AF6-A171-A43C8414C3D1"
_rev: "1-5779e6518d996fddf8e38f2c436db506"
drivers: Array[3] 0: "Martin" 1: "Vlada" 2: "Jan" length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

EDIT: Now I realized that I "see" the variable only in factory, but not in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, once you're asynchronous you need to continue writing asynchronous code. Look at your `get` function:

```
get: function(date){
    db.get(date, function(err, doc) {
        return doc
    });
},
```

That `return doc` doesn't return from `get`, it returns from `db.get`. Your top-level function is just a void call. But, even if you return from an asynchronous callback, you'll still have a void return because JavaScript evaluates return values *synchronously*.  I'm not familiar with PouchDB but scanning the docs, it look like it only supports [Continuation Passing Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). This means the way to get your result would be to either provide a callback or to create a promise around PouchDB methods. Here's how to do both:

**Callback**

```
get: function(date, callback){
    db.get(date, function(err, doc) {
        // do whatever logic needs to be done beforehand, then...
        if("function" === typeof callback){
            callback.call(null, err, doc);
        }
    });
},

// usage
dbFactory.get('2EC8999B-FC24-4AF6-A171-A43C8414C3D1', function(err, doc){
    $scope.drivers = doc;
});
```

**Promise**

```
// need to include $q dependency in your factory..

get: function(date){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    db.get(date, function(err, doc) {
        if(err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(doc);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},

// usage
dbFactory.get('2EC8999B-FC24-4AF6-A171-A43C8414C3D1').then( 
    function onSuccess(doc){
        $scope.drivers = doc;
    },
    function onError(err){
        $scope.drivers = null;
    });
```

Personally, I prefer the promise style. Before Angular 1.2, you could bind UI directly to a promise and it would be automatically resolved. In 1.2, you have to opt-in to this functionality. I believe the opt-in will be removed in 1.3. The reason I prefer the promise style is because the services and factories you write remain fairly consistent with the Angular core library.